# how to install module onto linux kernel 2.6.29

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I plan to install module usbserial.ko into my linux kernel 2.6.29, anybody knows the procedure? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Note that this question is not about programming, so it's more suitable for superuser.com. As soon as it has five close-votes, it will be moved there automatically.

Comment: In the meantime, maybe you could edit your question to add more context: Why do you want to do this? What Linux distribution? What device do you want to use?

Answer (score 4):

If the module is compiled with your kernel headers, you should be able to put it in /lib/modules/2.6.29... Depending on your distro, the name of the directory under modules might be different.

After placing the module in that directory, you can run:

```
depmod -a
```

and then try and load the module using:

```
modprobe usbserial
```

Again, the module has to be compiled with your current kernel sources version or else it probably won't load correctly (check the output of modprobe).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should insert that module in to the kernel.Then write an application to work with that module.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see what this answer adds, especially a year and a half later.